# get week number from date into dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have a database table containing a row of dates in DateTime format. what I need to do is get all the distinct weeks numbers of the available dates. for example if I have the following dates:

```
03-JAN-13 
04-JAN-13
09-JAN-13
```

the sql query would give me the following weeks numbers: 1 and 2.
PS: afterwards I will put these values in a dropdownlist (no problem with that step).

So can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Note, in some cultures the week # may exceed 52 ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you could use the following to get week numbers.

SQL Server you would use [`DatePart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
select distinct datepart(week, dates) WeekNo
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4555/3)

In MySQL you could use [`Week()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week):

```
select distinct week(dates)
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6f6a/2)

In Oracle, you could use [`to_char()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php):

```
select distinct to_char(dates, 'W') WeekNo
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63922/4)

In PostgreSQL you can use the following:

```
select distinct extract(WEEK from dates) WeekNO
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/da8f7/3)

Replace the `yourtable` with your table name and `dates` with your date column.

Edit #1: If you are using MS Access then you can still use [`DatePart()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datepart-function-HA001228812.aspx) (this was tested in MS Access 2003):

```
SELECT distinct datepart("ww", dates) as WeekNo
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: I am using microsoft access

Comment: the first solution you put for me didn't work.. I got this error:Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: @zahidaoui see my latest update, I added a query for MS Access. I just wrote and tested it is MS Access 2003

Comment: ok I tried it, and here is part of the code i wrote:

OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT distinct datepart('ww', date_time) WeekNo from temperature ", cn);
        OleDbDataReader dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

and got this error :Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'datepart('ww', date_time) WeekNo'.

Comment: @zahidaoui see my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @Remou Is `Format(Date(),"ww")` the preferred method in MS Access?

Comment: Not that I know, but it is valid, and was asked previous to this question. You are missing an As.

Comment: @Remou ok, thanks for that. I fixed the `AS`. I was not aware they previously asked this question.

Comment: No problem. I am just being awkward :)

Answer (score 0):

In your on load event, or wherever you want, you will put this VBA code

```
      Me!myCombo.RowSource = "yourquerytexthere;"
```

(Or whatever query you go with..probably whichever one you're using from your last question that Remou answered for you).

I think in this question, you already know what you want to query, you are just asking about setting the control.

That code is just

```
    Me!myCombo.RowSource = "yourquerystring"
```

like

```
    Me!myCombo.RowSource = "SELECT distinct datepart("ww", dates) FROM yourtable;"
```

Where Me!myCombo is the name of your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Annual ISO week# table - Oracle SQL query:

```
-- ISO_WK# --
 SELECT mydate
      , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') wk_starts
      , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') + 7 - 1/86400 wk_ends
      , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'IW')) ISO_WK#  
  FROM
   (
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-1 + LEVEL AS mydate  
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
    (-- First day of curr year - first day of past year --
      SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'YEAR') "Num of Days"   
        FROM dual
    )
  )
/
```