# get month name from date into dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have an Access database table containing a row of dates in DateTime format. what I need to do is get all the distinct month names of the available dates into my asp.net page. For example if I have the following dates:

```
03-JAN-13 
04-JAN-13
09-FEB-13
```

the sql query would give me the following month names: JAN and FEB.
After searching the web i found that the following sql query is supposed to give me what I need:

```
OleDbCommand cmd5 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT distinct DATENAME( 'mm', date_time) as MonthName from temperature ", cn);
```

but when I run my asp.net website, I get the following exception:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Undefined function 'DATENAME' in expression.
```

PS: afterwards I will put these string values in a dropdownlist (no problem with that step).
So can anybody tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use **DatePart** instead of **DateName**

Comment: i tried .. it worked perfectly for weeks but didn't work for months.

Comment: Not much different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220630/get-week-number-from-date-into-dropdownlist/14220722#comment19724725_14220722 is it? Especially of you use the right values http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php

Comment: it is actually the same ... at least that's what I though first .. byt apparently I cannot do it the same way.. hence i asked this question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Access, the syntax should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MonthName(Month ( date_column )) as MonthName from temperature
```

Because the `MonthName` function expects an Integer and the `Month` function returns the Integer value of the Month.

See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php) and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/monthname.php) for complete details

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Month()` function to get the month number of a given date, then feed that to the `MonthName()` function.

```
SELECT distinct MonthName(Month(date_time)) as [MonthName]
from temperature
```

The alias, *MonthName*, is a reserved word so I enclosed the alias in square brackets.

Another way to get what you want would be to use the `Format()` function.

```
SELECT distinct Format(date_time, 'mmmm') as [MonthName]
from temperature
```

I'm not sure which would be faster; you could try both.